# How to make my ANOVA code yield same result each time?

Tags: r

I have 3 groups with known n, mean, sd. I want to do ANOVA analysis so I generate simulating using rnorm and use ANOVA function as usual. Why is the result different each time? And how to fix it?
Thank you for your time!

```
g1 <- data.frame(g=1, hem=rnorm(n=16, mean=8.712, sd=0.844))
g2 <- data.frame(g=2, hem=rnorm(n=10, mean=10.63, sd=1.284))
g3 <- data.frame(g=3, hem=rnorm(n=15, mean=12.3, sd=0.942))
sdat <- rbind(g1, g2, g3)
sdat$g <- factor(sdat$g)

bartlett.test(hem ~ g, data=sdat)

anova(aov(hem ~ g, data=sdat))
```

I tried install the old rpsychi package, the result is consistent, however I still want to make sure the 2 methods to match.

Comment: When using random numbers one must issue a `set.seed` command first to ensure that the random numbers generated are reproducible.  e.g. `set.seed(123)`

Comment: Adding onto what @G.Grothendieck said, is this the data you're actually using that isn't reproducing? Or is this just the example you made for this post? I'm trying to clarify whether there's real data somewhere that you're having an issue with, or if it's just that you didn't set the seed

Comment: It's real data, there are 3 groups with pre-defined n, mean and SD. The rnorm function is used just to make a dataframe to use aov function. Also, I tried `set.seed(123)`, the output is still inconsistent with F value and Pr(>F) all over place.